# Move posts from a non-wordpress site to wordpress

Tags: posts, database, migration

an old web site (not created in wordpress) has many posts and its schema database differs from wordpress schema database.

I need to move posts from that site to wordpress. What is the best way?

I was trying to insert content into  wp_posts table through mysql, thus this doesn't work very well because when I view the post an 404 occurs. And, moreover I think this is not a good solution.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

If the previous posts are a service supported by WordPress' importer you could try using that. https://wordpress.org/support/article/importing-content/

If that doesn't support your previous blog service you could try WP All Import http://www.wpallimport.com/

I've used both of these methods with pretty good success.

Comment: I've used wp all import, and it showed a good result.